# RxSwift - .subscribe vs .subscribeNext what is the difference?

Tags: rx-java, rx-swift, reactivex

What is the difference betweeen these two operators ? http://reactivex.io dont mention .subscribeNext at all.

Comment: `subscribeNext()` will only receive emitted values, and not `onComplete` or `onError` indications.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

In RxSwift versions older than 3, `subscribeNext(_: Value -> ())` was a specialized version of `subscribe(_: Event<Value> -> ())`.

`subscribe(_:)` would be triggered for every cases of event, namely `.next(Value)`, `.error(Error)` and `.completed`.

`subscribeNext` would trigger only for `.next(Value)`, unpacking `Value` first.

As of RxSwift version 3, `subscribeNext` is now

```
func subscribe(
  onNext: ((Value) -> ())? = nil,
  onError: ((Error) -> ())? = nil,
  onCompleted: (() -> ())? = nil, 
  onDisposed: () -> () = nil
)
```

The nil default values enabling users to call `subscribe` only with the callbacks they are interested about.